# Find the minimal volume ellipsoid that will enclose $n$ points of $N$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

We're given $K$ points in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$, we need to select $n$ points such that the volume of the enclosing ellipsoid will be minimal in comparison with other $n$ points.

I don't understand how to turn these "exactly $n$ points" into a constraint for this problem. I guess, I'll use some quadratic solver (CVX), state the minimization problem. We define an ellipsoid as $(x - c)^{T}Q(x - c)$.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to find a minimum volume ellipsoid that contains the $K$ points?

Comment: Sorry @copper.hat. Let me rephrase. We have $K$ points, among which we need to find a set (of points) of size $n$ that will be enclosed by an ellipsoid of the smallest volume among other sets of the same size. ($K$ and $n$ are the parameters of the task and will be given)

Comment: [Related](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/40494/20417)